# How to rotate a PHP array each monday

Tags: php, arrays

I'm rather new to PHP and I have an array and I want it to rotate each Monday it rotates, what I'm trying to do is display the first 5 entries in this array, and then each Monday it pushes it forward by one.

This is what I came up with so far

```
$monday = array("James", "George", "Rob", "Martin", "Arthur", "Bob", "Tom", 
"Julie");
array_push($monday, array_shift($monday));

echo $monday[1], $monday[2], $monday[3], $monday[4], $monday[5];
```

So this week it would show for example

- James
- George
- Rob
- Martin
- Arthur

Then week two it would show

- George
- Rob
- Martin
- Arthur
- Bob

Then this would keep going like this!

Any ideas?

Comment: and what after last user name comes, means if last 5 showed and then after last five, 5 users will come or only 4 or after last it will start with first user again ?

Comment: this can be achieved using (number of elements in the names array + week number http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php [W])

Comment: you have to use some other logic with date and time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use at global level,

```
function array_rotate($array, $shift)
{
    if (!is_array($array) || !is_numeric($shift)) {
        if (!is_array($array)) {
            error_log(__FUNCTION__ . ' expects first argument to be array; ' . gettype($array) . ' received.');
        }
        if (!is_numeric($shift)) {
            error_log(__FUNCTION__ . ' expects second argument to be numeric; ' . gettype($shift) . " `$shift` received.");
        }
        return $array;
    }
    $shift %= count($array); //we won't try to shift more than one array length
    if ($shift < 0) {
        $shift += count($array);
    }
//handle negative shifts as positive
    return array_slice(array_merge(array_slice($array, $shift, null, true), array_slice($array, 0, $shift, true)), 0, 5, true);
}
$monday = array("James", "George", "Rob", "Martin", "Arthur", "Bob", "Tom",
    "Julie");
$monday = array_rotate($monday, 4); // 4 is number to be shifted
print_r($monday);
```

Here is working [code](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/567272abf94ab0afdc1900bc3e68ed7e3f87f920).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get it to shift forward on Mondays? :o

Comment: You are asking regarding that 4 integer. Change that as per your requirement, i.e. first monday pass 1 to it. if second pass 2 to it. If you are using database. You can take that number from there as week number and pass in place of 4

Comment: Thanks! Though maybe im doing something wrong, If i put 1 into that $shift I get Array ( [0] => George [1] => Rob [2] => Martin [3] => Arthur [4] => Bob ) if I put 2 into that $shift I get Array ( [0] => Rob [1] => Martin [2] => Arthur [3] => Bob [4] => Tom ) there not shifting one to the right if you get me? :s

Comment: I shared working code, have you tried changing number 4 to something else ?

Comment: I think its just going the wrong way around they are moving left not right, is there a way i can reverse it?

Comment: Ok. Do one thing. Update you question with more than 2 outputs means more than 2 or 3 mondays, let me also know, what is your requirement, as it is shifting from left to right. as from 1st to last. is moving right i.e. from left to right

Comment: Okay, so the idea is that the array will move from left to right if that makes sense. At the moment it moves from Right to Left, so if I increase the value from 3 to 4 they have all moved left, this is what happens when I use the same array but change the $shift to 1 2 3 4 5 6 Array ( [0] => George [1] => Rob [2] => Martin [3] => Arthur [4] => Bob ) 
Array ( [0] => Martin [1] => Arthur [2] => Bob [3] => George [4] => Rob ) 
Array ( [0] => Arthur [1] => Bob [2] => George [3] => Rob [4] => Martin ) 
Array ( [0] => Bob [1] => George [2] => Rob [3] => Martin [4] => Arthur )

Comment: Array ( [0] => George [1] => Rob [2] => Martin [3] => Arthur [4] => Bob ) 
Array ( [0] => Rob [1] => Martin [2] => Arthur [3] => Bob [4] => George )

Comment: Something isn't working correctly in this function http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d18715c1d4bef927b43a1e32d629f1d7a02fe625 look at 10 and 9 it didn't shift correctly, unless im doing something stupid?

Comment: Yes you are right, because you are overriding $monday array in loop, so it will override. and you are incrementing x before its use and some other issues, check this corrected [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f25ee7ad673e3e9a71447806d81f57cd20e16640)

Comment: Thanks man, its all working okay now I've put an example of what I used this for http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4608f4a12020cedbf3580d619bb05386215e8325 if you want to and have time, mind checking over that everything looks correct? :D

Answer (score 0):

If I am not understand the question wrongly this might be what you want.

```
$timestamp = time();
if(date('D', $timestamp) === 'Mon') {
    $temp = $monday[0]; 
    for($i=0;$i<=sizeof($monday)-1;$i++) {
        $monday[$i] = $monday[$i+1];
    }
    $monday[sizeof($monday)-1] = $temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Array Declaration
$array = array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6");

//Shift First element to end and display.

array_push($array, $array[0]);
unset($array[0]);
$array = array_values($a);

echo $array[0].$array[1].$array[2].$array[3].$array[4];
```

Simply add the first element of the array to the end and then unset the first value and reset the indexing.

If you are asking about how to do this every Monday then you should look at making a Cron Job to run everyday and use how Lenox described to check whether it's Monday. That way everyday it will check whether it's Monday and rotate the array as you want. Alternatively you can run the Cron job every week.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array which covers all 52 weeks.

```
$names = [a, b, c]; $rotated = [];

foreach(range(0,51) as $week) { // weeks
    $rotated[] = $names[$week % count($names)];
}

// [a, b, c, a, b, c ... a, b, c]
```

Then use array_slice (you'll need some conditions for boundaries - week 51, 52).

```
$week = 2;
$names = array_slice($rotated, $week-1, count($names));

// [b, c, a]
```